# Map and Scrollview in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I'm trying to display a map as a part of a ScrollView, but the ScrollView seems to just cause the map to disappear. This happens whether the Map is a child of the ScrollView or otherwise.

Any advice? (Please forgive my really bad code, I'm learning.)

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var person: Person
    @State private var data = Data()
    @State private var showingEditView = false
    @State private var savedLocation: [SavedLocation] = []
    @State private var coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @State private var annotation = MapMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(), tint: Color.orange)
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: self.data) ?? UIImage())
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(maxWidth: proxy.size.width * 0.7)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1))
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                    
                    Text(person.name ?? "")
                    Text(person.email ?? "")
                    Text(person.phoneNumber ?? "")
                    Text(person.notes ?? "")
                }
                
                Map(coordinateRegion: $coordinateRegion, interactionModes: MapInteractionModes.init(), showsUserLocation: false, userTrackingMode: nil, annotationItems: savedLocation) { annotation in
                    MapMarker(coordinate: annotation.location, tint: Color.orange)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Edit") {
                        self.showingEditView = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                ProfilePictureLoader.getProfilePicture(using: person.id!) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        self.data = data
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
                self.coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: person.coordinate!.latitude, longitude: person.coordinate!.longitude), latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
                let savedLocation = SavedLocation(id: person.id!, lat: person.coordinate!.latitude, long: person.coordinate!.longitude)
                self.savedLocation.append(savedLocation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you give the `Map` an explicit frame? Like `.frame(width: 300, height: 300)`? Right now, it's inside a `ScrollView` *and* a `GeometryReader`, which will both fill all available space and, at least in the case of `ScrollView`, won't constrain a child `View`'s size.

Comment: @jnpdx That worked, cheers! Thanks for the explanation as well.

Comment: Sure -- I've added it as an answer so it can be accepted. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ScrollView` takes all available space and doesn't lend size constraints to child views. Because `Map` acts similarly, with no size constraints from the parent, within a `ScrollView`, it can just collapse into nothing (eg a frame of `0,0`).

To fix this, you can add an explicit `frame` modifier to the map to tell it what size to be:

```
Map(...) { ... }.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
```